# WPF DataGrid - How detect if full row is selected?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have DataGrid in my WPF application, and I want to run a function in the `SelectedCellsChanged` event, but only if the row is not fully selected, which happens if the user clicks at the header of the row.

My table has only one column.

I've tried the following code and always the value of `rowContainer.IsSelected` is false.

How can I do this?

```vb
Private Sub DataGridEx_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SelectionChanged

    If SelectedCells.Count <> 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not SelectedCells.First.Item.ToString.Contains("NewItemPlaceholder") Then

            Me.TheDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                Sub()
                    Dim cell = SelectedCells.First
                    Dim index = Items.IndexOf(cell.Item) + 1
                    Dim rowContainer As DataGridRow = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)

                    If rowContainer IsNot Nothing Then
                        If Not rowContainer.IsSelected Then
                            ' run a function here
                        End If
                    End If
                End Sub,
                DispatcherPriority.Input)

     End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the row container for the select cell and check its `IsSelected` property:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg.SelectedCells != null && dg.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        var cell = dg.SelectedCells[0];
        var row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item) as DataGridRow;
        if (row != null && row.IsSelected)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("row is selected...");
        }
    }
}
```

This should work if you are using a `SelectionUnit` of `CellOrRowHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is force your datagrid to the SelectionUnit as FullRow, Cell or CellOrRowHeader

```
dim dg = new DataGrid();
dg.SelectionUnit == System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
dg.SelectionUnit == System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSelectionUnit.CellOrRowHeader;
dg.SelectionUnit == System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell;
```

In XAML, you would just apply the property setting

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="FullRow" ... >
```

Then you should be able to simply hook into the SelectedCellsChanged or SelectionChanged method to act on it...

Then you don't have to worry about a partial row selection of just a cell or two and not trigger an entire row you are expecting to process.  By forcing a full row, it will have in its collection one entry per row.  Otherwise, if you have it by cell and have 5 columns wide and person selects 3 cells on two rows, it will have 6 cells representing the same row for each individual cell covering the rows..

HTH